# Does Jourdonnais's ability negate all or half of Slab the Killer's attack on a successful draw?

Tags: bang

The other night we had Slab the Killer in play as well as Jourdonnais. Here are their abilities as listed on the cards...

Jourdonnais

> Whenever he is the target of a BANG!, he may "draw!" : on a Heart, he is missed.

Slab the Killer

> Player needs 2 Missed! cards to cancel his BANG! card.

When Slab the Killer plays a BANG! against Jourdonnais, how is Jourdonnais's ability applied? Obviously if his ability is unsuccessful, 2 Missed! cards would have to be played, but what happens if Jourdonnais successfully draws a Heart? Is the entire attack cancelled out? Or will an additional Missed! card still need to be played?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Jourdonnais' ability is essentially a built in barrel.

**Another Missed! card is needed** in addition to drawing the Heart to avoid Slab the Killer's BANG!

This was answered by the designer, Emiliano Sciarra on [Boardgamegeek](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/article/24805):

> Yes. Even if the effect of the Barrel triggers by drawing a Heart card from the deck, you will need another Missed! card from the hand to avoid the hit from Slab.
>
> Since Jourdonnais has a Barrel built in, he may "draw!" once to see if he plays an automatic Missed!. After that, if he drew a Heart he will need a real Missed! from his hand to dodge Slab's shot. Otherwise, he will need two Missed! cards, as anyone else.

Comment: If he had a barrel could he use his ability and the barrel in order to miss a bang from slab?

Answer (score 2):

Man, that's a good question.

Offhand from the phrasing you pasted I would say that Jourdonnais wins out here - his ability does not say "on a Heart, he is 'Missed!'", it just says "he is missed."  That would seem to be completely unrelated to the playing of Missed! cards, which is the only thing mentioned for Slab the Killer's ability.

It seems like it might be unbalanced (although the odds of a Heart are only roughly 1/4), but I think I would personally interpret this that a successful "draw" by Jourdonnais will cause even Slab to miss him.

Answer (score -1):

Because Jourdonnais' ability says that you can only block a "BANG!" With two "MISSED" cards Jourdonnais' ability wouldn't even help if you drew a heart. You need "MISSED" cards, a barrel wont block Jourdonnais' ability either.